# MVC empty WebSite project based on aspx pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In Visual Studio we have a two ways that create the web projects.
I create the "WebSite" project, empty-project (like: File -> New -> WebSite... and so on).
After that, when the WebSite created I want to make it to MVC WebSite with ASPX, and not Razor pages.

- [I decide create the MVC WebSite not Project Site, with this way, because the Visual Studio doesn't provide us WebSite with MVC template based aspx pages].

After creating some pages I want to create and integrate any Razor page.

Describe for question:
IF I attempt use in the Razor view page - " @model MyWebSite " it does not discovering, and I can't use with the ViewBag property later

Question:
What Can I do ?
What NuGet packeg I need install or what dll recourse I need adding to Bin folder of project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Razor with an existing ASP.NET WebSite. Simply open your website using the WebMatrix tool and start adding CSHTML files. One caveat is that if your website is using WebForms controls the WebMatrix tool will not provide any help working with them in existing aspx pages. Additionally, Razor does not support WebForms so you will not be able to add something like  to a CSHTML file.

Comment: I have additional question.

Comment: If I create the standard WebSite MVC Razor, not Project MVC Razor template. How can I use with keyword [**@model**] in Razor View? I Thank to you for help.

Comment: I am not sure weather you are using MVC. I think you have created WebSite using Razor engine but not MVC. You can use Razor Engine with out MVC.